# tomcat eclipse and WTP with maven

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, maven-2, eclipse-wtp

I have a maven multi-moudule project. I tried to use WTP with Eclipse  3.6 and i can't figure out how to configure my project so everything will work right with tomcat. Sometimes not all the classes are being published or/and the provided scope jar are deployed to lib dir (even though they are not supposed to). 
 I know there are alot of sites which explain how to do it. But still i find it hard to deploy my multi module project on tomcat 6 server bundled in eclipse. 
 Anyone has easy way?
 Thanks,

**EDIT**: I downloaded Eclipse 64bit and Maven Integration for Eclipse\WTP and then this seems ok. But still i can't understand why it doesn't work on 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

look in the plugin marketplace for a free plugin called m2e-wtp.  That will take care of the provided scope issues.  As for classes not being deployed, the usual places I look at are the deployment assembly and/or Java Build Path.  Make sure that the entries (and the dependent modules) are all there and located in the right place.